# how to make vim colorscheme work on big sur terminal?

Tags: terminal, colorscheme, macos

[some say I need to install iTerm because osx terminal only support 16 colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653842/3012473)

but when I check the terminal.app it use xterm-256 and [it support 256 color test](https://askubuntu.com/a/821163/266636)

[some say default osx doesn't support 256 colors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1653842/3012473) (see the comment)

so I install newest screen from brew

but it still not showing correct color

my [.vimrc](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/buncis/584e7014f08e8e129f0593f3b3ba5010/raw/c410b2a8f74dd2280b59856ff61e3c8e6ed32ede/.vimrc)

I also have check the color support using `:set t_Co` it says 256

the vim and the themes is just fine in gvim and iTerm2

is it because the ANSI color settings in terminal.app?

I think this is because my terminal.app not support 24 color it fail to run this [script](https://github.com/tclamb/iTerm2/blob/d0ecb297727a59c9ee551144caeade675d9ae04b/tests/24-bit-color.sh)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Can you confirm that Vim thinks it can do 256 colors, with `:set t_Co?` ? What about termguicolors, what does Vim say for `:verb set tgc?` ?

Comment: `:set t_Co`return 256 `:verb set tgc` return nothing

Comment: The colorscheme you're using [should](https://github.com/glepnir/oceanic-material/blob/900f487a1e8229a12f247a0cb7a533fe258945ae/colors/oceanic_material.vim#L21) work with 256 colors only... But not sure what you mean by "not showing correct color". You're correct that Terminal.app supports 256-color, but it doesn't support 24-bit color (termguicolors is 24-bit color). With 24-bit color you'll of course have more colors, so themes can be more precise about their choices. If you find you need 24-bit color, I suggest switch to iTerm2.

Comment: oh I see so any workaround so that Terminal.app support 24-bit color?

for now I use tmux I think its the screen that doesn't support 24-bit color

Comment: What do you mean by "a workaround to support TrueColor" when the application doesn't support it at all?

Comment: @Matt I'm thinking something like editing config `.screenrc` or recompiling with 24color flag like that, I think we could close this questions, my current workaround is using tmux inside Terminal.app to get what I want.

Comment: I really don't see how using tmux would fix anything... Except for the change in `$TERM`, so I'm betting if you start Vim outside tmux you'll see `&t_Co=16` (well, not 256) and that would explain it. (But then, it's not really tmux "fixing" something, but just getting your `$TERM` settings right.) There's no way to configure 24-bit color in Terminal.app, the program just doesn't support it and there's no way to change that, really... iTerm2 has support for 24-bit color (and it's generally a better emulator), so switching to iTerm2 is always an option.

Comment: I don't understand it too, but if I run tmux inside my Terminal.app somehow it show the correct vim colorschemes, but outside tmux the color is wrong.